# Unable to understand Rates of Change, sphere in this case

Tags: calculus, derivatives, volume

I have a problem.  Volume of the sphere is given as: $$V(r) = \frac{4}{3}\pi r^3$$
I am then told (part A of the question) to `find the average rate of change of V with respect to r, when r changes from 5 ft to 8 ft.` (exact quote)

I know we're going to form up the equation:
$$\frac{dV}{dt} = \frac{dV}{dr} \frac{dr}{dt}$$

After deriving $V(r)$, we get: $$\frac{dV}{dr} = 4\pi r^2$$  Is this correct so far?

Now, I don't have a RATE of change with respect to the radius.  I have a change from 5 feet to 8 feet, but it does not indicate a duration of time over which this occurs.  Is this missing or am I misunderstanding what I'm needing to require.

The answer to this question states that part A is $387 ft^3$

The problem is that I have no idea how they got to the answer.

I **THINK** that I'm supposed to use a time range of 1 minute for part A, meaning $\frac{dr}{dt} = 3 ft/min$.  However, $$\frac{dV}{dr}\frac{dr}{dt} = 4\pi (5^2)(3 ft/min) = 942.4778$$ which is DEFINITELY not the answer.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: If you are looking for the "average" rate of change, couldn't you just calculate the volume at r=5 and r=8 and not use calculus? I've never seen a question ask for the average rate of change in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're thinking far too hard. A *derivative* finds *instantaneous* rate-of-change - which is explicitly not what the question was asking for. You have correctly computed the instantaneous rate of change with respect to time at the moment that $r = 5$; this is more or less irrelevant to the average rate of change.

*Average* rate of change is much simpler to compute, and takes no calculus whatsoever. For example, if I travel $500$ miles in $8$ hours, the *average* rate of change of my position is just $500/8 = 62.5 mph$, even though at some points in time my *instantaneous* rate of change may be much higher.

Secondly, you computed $\frac{dV}{dt}$; the question is asking with respect to *r*, which means that even if it were asking for instantaneous rate of change you'd want $\frac{dV}{dr}$ instead.

So what you want is just $\frac{\Delta V}{\Delta r}$ - which is just $\frac{V(8) - V(5)}{8 - 5}$.

Comment: In which case, I should just use $\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3$ substituting 5 and 8 respectively, then dividing by 3.  This gives me 540.3539.

Comment: It looks to me like there's an error in the solutions. $387$ happens to be $8^3 - 5^3$; oddly, they seem to have stopped there and neglected both the division by $3$ and the coefficient of $\frac{4}{3}\pi$. It's worth noting that this was suspicious to begin with - the rate of change of something involving $\pi$ is almost never a whole number. I'd recommend asking your teacher or professor to confirm this.

Comment: Is this math correct and what you get as the correct answer? $\frac{4}{3}\pi 5^3 = 523.599$, $\frac{4}{3}\pi 8^3 = 2144.66$.  $(2144.66 - 523.599)/3 = 540.3536$

Comment: Also, you are correct.  There are MANY instances of us correcting him during in-class demonstrations, so this would not surprise me.

Comment: Yes, that solution's correct.

Comment: Just so you are aware: Your explanation, however simple it may seem, helped the ONLY section I was having a problem with click into place.  While I was in full-on panic mode prior, I'm going into the exam with a lot of confidence.  Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: I'm personally crediting you with at least 25% of an exam I just completed.  You're a scholar and a gentleman.